# count row color in datagrid

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

this is my code what should i do ..? i use color for row and want type number of color in label14,16 i try many code but not work

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        var now = DateTime.Now;
        var expirationDate = DateTime.Parse(row.Cells[6].Value.ToString());
        var sevenDayBefore = expirationDate.AddDays(-3);
        label12.Text = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows.Count);

        if (now > sevenDayBefore && now < expirationDate)
        {
         label14.Text = (what i type here to count yellow)
            row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
        }
        else if (now > expirationDate)
        {
            label16.Text = (what i type here to count red)            
            row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: add a variable that increments inside if or else and assign it to label12 or label16

Comment: Thank you dear for your response i do this but it count 1 for many rows

Comment: Can you add more details to your question?

Comment: Maybe i dont know what are you want, give us more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
public void CountRowColor()
    {
        int red = 0, yellow = 0;

        foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            if (row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor == Color.Red)
                red++;
            if (row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor == Color.Yellow)
                yellow++;
        }

        this.label14.Text = yellow.ToString();
        this.label16.Text = red.ToString();
    }
```